Capture and use output from defined GitHub Action
I'm setting up a GitHub Actions workflow using the ruff-action from Astral. The workflow runs ruff format and ruff check --fix whenever a pull request (PR) is opened. However, I want to capture the output of these commands and include them in a comment on the pull request.
It seems that the ruff-action doesn't expose the command output directly through the action's outputs (only the ruff version). The alternative I've considered is installing python and ruff directly, but I'm hoping to work with the action if possible.
Here is what I have
name: ruff-action
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Format code
        id: format
        uses: astral-sh/ruff-action@v2.0.0
        with:
          args: "format"
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Commit format changes (if any)
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Apply Ruff formatting" || exit 0
          git push origin HEAD:${{ github.head_ref }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Check code
        id: check
        uses: astral-sh/ruff-action@v2.0.0
        with:
          args: "check --fix"
        continue-on-error: true  

      - name: Commit fixed lint errors (if any)
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Apply Ruff lint fixes" || exit 0
          git push origin HEAD:${{ github.head_ref }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Add output to PR
        run: |
          echo "#### Ruff Changes" > ruff_output.txt

          # Add format output
          echo "<details><summary>Format</summary>" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo '```' >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "${{ steps.format.outputs }}" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo '```' >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "</details>" >> ruff_output.txt

          # Add check output
          echo "<details><summary>Check</summary>" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo '```' >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "${{ steps.check.outputs }}" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo '```' >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "" >> ruff_output.txt
          echo "</details>" >> ruff_output.txt

          # Truncate if file size exceeds 65k characters
          file_size=$(wc -m <ruff_output.txt)         
          if [ "$file_size" -gt 65000 ]; then
            head -c 65000 ruff_output.txt > temp_ruff_output.txt
            mv temp_ruff_output.txt ruff_output.txt
          fi
          
          # Post the comment with the output
          gh issue comment ${{ github.event.number }} --body-file ruff_output.txt
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          GH_REPO: ${{ github.repository }}



Setting args with relevant flags to dump the output to a file seems to be the way as suggested on your reported issue: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-action/issues/28.

that issue was opened by me! Hahaha
